Start process after directory modified, but wait for idle
I'd like to start a process a few seconds after a directory has been modified, batching processing of multiple files.
If I define a systemd path unit, my "service" is started immediately after the first file is created. This will lead to eventual consistency, but is suboptimal:

the first process starts processing the first file
the second and further processes are held up waiting for a lockfile
after processing the first file completes, another process gets the lock, processes the remaining files as a batch
then the remaining processes acquire the lock one after the other, find the directory empty, and exit

What I'd like to do is, after the first notification is received, wait for five seconds without a notification, then start the process. If more files are created afterwards, the process should be run a second time after the first instance finishes.
Because the process removes the files from the watched directory, deletion notifications will be generated during a successful run. I'm okay with running the process a second time if only deletions are received, but ideally I'd like to skip that as well.
Can I do this with systemd, or do I need to dust off some old Unix tool?
